# Continuity in topology

Tags: general-topology

I came across an exercise problem which says:

Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ with topology $T= \{\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{3\}, \emptyset\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$ with topology $t=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\emptyset\}$. When is $F:X\rightarrow Y$ continuous with respect to these topologies?

My question is how can you possibly generate a map between these sets without the actual definition. For e.g Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be defined by f(x)=x and then we can check for continuity. I know the definition of continuous functions is different in topology but still.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $F:X\to Y$ is continuous if $F^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$. In other words, in your case $F:X\to Y$ is continuous if $F^{-1}[U]\in T$ for each $U\in t$. Now $F^{-1}[\{1,2\}]=\{1,2,3\}\in T$ no matter what $F$ is, and $F^{-1}[\varnothing]=\varnothing\in T$ no matter what $F$ is, so it’s only the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ in $t$ that might cause trouble. You need to choose $F$ so that $F^{-1}[\{1\}]$ and $F^{-1}[\{2\}]$ are members of $T$. Moreover, $F$ sends every element of $X$ either to $1$ or to $2$, so every element of $X$ must belong to exactly one of $F^{-1}[\{1\}]$ and $F^{-1}[\{2\}]$. There are only a few ways to split $X$ into two disjoint open sets. One of them is to split it as $X\cup\varnothing$; you could have $F^{-1}[\{1\}]=X$ and $F^{-1}[\{2\}]=\varnothing$, meaning that $F$ is the constant function on $X$ that sends every member of $X$ to $1$.

- What other continuous $F:X\to Y$ corresponds to this splitting of $X$?
- How else can you split $X$ into two open parts, and what continuous $F:X\to Y$ do you then get?

Comment: The other way of splitting can be $\{1,2\}\cup\{3\}$. So, it will be $F^{-1}[\{1\}]=\{1,2\}$ and $F^{-1}[\{2\}]=\{3\}$

Comment: @RutherfordMark: Or the other way around. Thus, there are altogether four continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: I see, I have one question why can't I take intersection say, $X \cap \{3\}$ and split that up?

Comment: @RutherfordMark: I’m not sure what you mean. How do you have it in mind to define $F$?

Comment: I know that $X\cap \{3\}$ is open. So, I can have $F^{-1}[\{1\}=X$ and $F^{-1}[\{2\}=\{3\}$

Comment: @RutherfordMark: You don’t have a function: you’re trying to send $3$ both to $1$ and to $2$.

Comment: I see. In the book the answer is given as $F(1)=F(2)$ what does that mean?

Comment: @RutherfordMark: Ah, yes, that is a nice way of describing them without actually writing out all four of them explicitly as we did here. The point is that every open set in $X$ that contains $1$ also contains $2$, and *vice versa*. Let $y=F(1)$; whether $y$ is $1$ or $2$, $\{y\}\in t$, so we must have $F^{-1}[\{y\}]\in T$ in order for $F$ to be continuous. $F^{-1}[\{y\}]$ must therefore be either $\{1,2\}$ or $X$, one of the two open sets in $X$ containing $1$; $2$ is in both of those, so $F(2)$ will necessarily be $y$. In other words, if $F$ is continuous, we can prove that $F(1)=F(2)$. ...

Comment: ... Conversely, if $F(1)=F(2)$, you can check that it doesn’t matter whether $F(3)=1$ or $F(3)=2$: $F$ will be continuous either way. Thus, $F$ is continuous if and only if $F(1)=F(2)$.